# Get Values from array object using String type object id

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Is there a way to get the values of an array object if we have the object id as String value

//assume this is a real object id value,

A PC send an array to my and then i get this id from a that PC as String (Using Sockets). I want to get the content of the array by using that object name.

## client

```
`
       Random random = new Random();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i<5 ; i++ ) {
            weatherDetails[i] = random.nextDouble() * 100;
        }
        out.println(weatherDetails);
```

`

## server

```
          while (true) {
      input = in.readLine();
      if (input == null) {
             return;
      }            
      System.out.println("Input value weather->" + input);//[D@514713
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "object ID"?

Comment: That reference id of the array object

Comment: It is just some hash code of the array (or reference), it is not based on any index in this array. If this is the array you want, well yeah, just use the `equals` method between the `array.toString()` result and the `input`. But store those in a `Map` would be more efficient to me if you want to store arrays to access them based on a `id`

Comment: Is there any way to get values from the array sent by client to server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstand the situation that you have created.

When you use

```
out.println(someObject);
```

What is printed out is the result of `someObject.toString`.

The default implementation of `toString` is a concatenation of the object's class name, a `@`, and the result of the object's `hashCode()` method.

Since an array is an object that doesn't override the `toString` method, you get the array's class name (for an array of type `double[]`, this will be `[D`), followed by `@`, followed by whatever hash code it is assigned in that JVM.

That is, the print contains no useful information at all.

In order to transfer the actual data, you should loop on the array and print its elements in some form that you'll be able to read.

Since you didn't do that, when you try to read the line, all you get is the meaningless string representation. This is **not** an object ID. It's **not** a reference of any kind. It's simply a meaningless concatenation of the array's type and hash code.

If you used something like

```
out.println(Arrays.toString(weatherDetails));
```

Then you would have the actual numbers in the output, in a format such as

```
[40.5,31.972,17.60,5.3]
```

You'll then be able to read it on the other side by removing the brackets, splitting on the commas and using `Double.parseDouble()` on each of the resulting elements.

Note that this is just one option. You can use other methods that actually loop and put the data in other ways. For example, put the number of elements in the first line, and one element on each of the following lines. Then on the reading side, read the first line, parse it as integer, and then you know how many lines to read, read each line and parse it. Or you can use a `DataOutputStream` or an `ObjectOutputStream`.

Just don't try to print an array directly. You don't get any useful information doing that.